# Does casting a primitive array in Java to an Object and back involve boxing?

Tags: java, primitive-types, boxing

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Msg {
    private Object msg;
    public byte[] getMsg() {
        return (byte[]) msg;
    }
    public void setMsg(byte[] msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Does setting and then getting the message involve autoboxing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Auto-boxing doesn't apply to arrays, at any time.

Even if it did, the array is an object, and it's the reference to *array object* you're casting, not the elements within it.

Comment: It's the reference to the array object that is cast, not the array object.

Answer (score 3):

Auto-boxing only occurs when you assign a primitive (`byte`) value (or variable) to a reference (`Byte`) variable.

Assigning an array (`byte[]`) to an `Object` variable only involves casting. That would be a static or implicit casting. Whereas the other way around involves an explicit (dynamic) casting.

Boxing each element of the array would require creating a whole new array (i.e. `Byte[]`). And in this case, that's not what's happening. You have only chosen to refer to the same array (`byte[]`) just using a variable of type `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

No. A primitive array *is* an object. Both the byte[] and Object references point to the same object.